# Ruby on rails create a new variable to make an each

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

i'm new into ruby on rails and i want to assign a variable to make an each like this

```
<% 3.times do |calendar| %>
 <% test = @lessons_calendar %>
   <% test.each do |lesson| %>
     display html here
   <% end %>
<% end %>
```

The thing is that in my controller i have assigned 3 variables like this @lessons_1 @lessons_2 and @lessons_3 but when i run the code it says undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass, how can i join the number created by calendar to the new variable ? Thanks

Comment: You don't want three instance variables, you want a single three element array named `@lessons`.

Comment: No, i need 3 instances, called each of them lessons_1 and 2 and 3, is for a calendar and each instance is a day

Comment: @mdiaz00147 As mu said, _you don't want 3 variables_. The way you generally code is is using a single variable of type Hash or Array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of below

```
<% 3.times do |calendar| %>
 <% test = @lessons_calendar %>
 <% test.each do |lesson| %>
   display html here
 <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Make changes in your controller as well as in view as below

Controller Code

```
# take new variable
 @lessons = []
 @lessons << @lessons_1
 @lessons << @lessons_2
 @lessons << @lessons_3
```

Now do code in view file as below

```
<% @lessons.each do |lesson| %>
  <% lesson.each do |ls| %>
    your code here
  <%end%>
<%end%>
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score -1):

```
<% 3.times do |calender| %>
   <%= @lessons_calendar.collect{ |lesson| Write Your Code Here }.join("").html_safe rescue 'No Record' %>
<% end %>
```

With in the collect iterator you can assign it to instance var if you want to. Thanks

Comment: It's really a terrible approach to use an inline rescue in a view. Also, what is `@ display html` doing?

Comment: @ display html is quite self explanatory. User can add here html or code.

Comment: No, it's not. It seems a variable and/or a method call.